# Gnuplot: Logscale seems to mess things up

Tags: gnuplot

I put an xlogscale in and it messed up the drawing of the gridlines.  The major x gridlines are no longer the same gray as the major y gridlines, they are the gray of the minor x and y gridlines.

The following to pictures show this.

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Thanks

[image: logscale]

[image: No logscale]

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set term pdfcairo size 15cm,10cm
set output 'FFT.pdf'

set datafile separator '    '
unset key

set border lw 4 back

set grid mxtics mytics xtics ytics lt 1 lc rgb 'gray70', lt 1 lc rgb 'gray90'

set mxtics 5
set mytics 5

set xrange [10:10e3]

set title 'Harmonic Distortion'
set xlabel 'Frequency [Hz]'
set ylabel 'Output Voltage [dB]'

set mxtics 10
set logscale x 10

plot 'FFT.dat' using ($1):(20*log10((($2**2)+($3**2))**0.5)-5.49074) with lines lw 4 lc rgb 'red'

set out
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this by using only `set mxtics`, without specifying any frequency:

```
set term pdfcairo size 15cm,10cm
set output 'FFT.pdf'

unset key
set samples 1000
set border lw 4 back

set grid xtics ytics mxtics mytics lc rgb 'blue' lt 1, lc rgb 'red' lt 1

set xrange [10:10000]
set mxtics
set mytics 5
set logscale x 10

plot sin(0.001*x) with lines lw 4 lc rgb 'green70'

set out
```

I used better distinguishable colors for the grid lines. The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

I don't know, why this happens. According to the documentation `set mxtics 10` should be fine. I will report this as a bug.

Comment: Thank you!  It is very strange indeed!

Comment: @user968243 I reported that as bug: [#1292 Logscale: superfluous minor grid line](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1292/).