# logarithmic scale with constant distances, how to fix?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a multirow data file with one column like this

```
0.2
1.5
0.9
4.3
...
```

When I set the xscale to log2, the xtics numbers are converted to logarithmic scale but the distance between xtics remain constant!

How can I fix that?

```
plot "rd_percent_streaming.txt" using ($0+1):1 with impulses
```

[image]

Comment: Thats how a logarithmic scale is defined! `log2(1) = 0`, `log2(4) = 2`, `log2(16) = 4`…

Comment: I am looking for similar xtics like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197459/gnuplot-logscale-seems-to-mess-things-up

Comment: @mahmood not sure how the graph on this link differs from your graph. The xtics behaviour is consistent, which is the way it should be with log scale.

Comment: Ok, you mean the minor ticks. Using `set mxtics` doesn't work properly for me with base 2. You could add the minor ticks manually, I don't know an other solution: `set xtics add (2 2, 3 2, 8 2, 12 2, 32 2, 48 2, 128 2, 192 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get gnuplot to use "proper" minor tics (`set mxtics ...`) with logscale of base 2. You can set those minor tics manually with e.g.

```
set logscale x 2
set xrange [1:16384]
set for [i=0:14:2] xtics add (2**(i+1) 2, 3*2**i 2)
plot x
```

[image]